# Javascript join two object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, nodes

So I have two Object Arrays that I need to make one Object Array.

```
var insertEpisode = [{
    "show_id":new ObjectId(req.body.show_id),
    "show_b":req.body.show_b,
    "season":new Double(req.body.season),
    "episode_no": new Double(req.body.episode_no),
    "title": req.body.title,
    "summary": podsummary,
    "description": description,
    "explicit":req.body.explicit,
    "enclosureurl":filesToEpisode[0].file.enclosureurl,
    "enclosurebyts": filesToEpisode[0].file.enclosurebyts,
    "duration":new Double(filesToEpisode[0].file.duration),
    }];
```

and if there is a image to go with the episode I have

```
if(image){
var image = [{"image":"this "}]
const array3 = insertEpisode.concat(image);
}
```

however that does not work. instead it added prints out like

```
[{"show_id":"6274a3a881cf417136a8a4ed","show_b":"insiderelationships","season":1,"episode_no":40,"title":"Test Title","summary":"A week ago a friend invited a couple of other couples over for dinner. Eventually, the food (but not the wine) was cleared off the table for what turned out to be some fierce Scrabbling.","description":"<![CDATA[<p>A week ago a friend invited aco</p>]]>","explicit":"false","enclosureurl":"URL TO mp3.mp3","enclosurebyts":"173080","duration":00:01:00},{"image":"this "}]
```

Instead it should look like

```
[{"show_id":"6274a3a881cf417136a8a4ed","show_b":"insiderelationships","season":1,"episode_no":40,"title":"Test Title","summary":"A week ago a friend invited a couple of other couples over for dinner. Eventually, the food (but not the wine) was cleared off the table for what turned out to be some fierce Scrabbling.","description":"<![CDATA[<p>A week ago a friend invited aco</p>]]>","explicit":"false","enclosureurl":"URL TO mp3.mp3","enclosurebyts":"173080","duration":00:01:00, "image":"this "}]
```

You can see the image part is joined into the first array.

Comment: `concat()` works on the arrays, it doesn't care about the elements. See `console.log([1,2].concat([3,4]))` instead of that eye-popping monstrosity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
if (image) {
    var image = [{"image":"this "}]
    const merged = {...insertEpisode, ...image};
}
```

Comment: I was able to make this work with some minor changes:

`if(im){ const image =[{"image":filesToEpisode[1].image.enclosureurl}]; const merged = {...insertEpisode[0], ...image[0]};}`

Answer (score 0):

```
const array3 = insertEpisode.map((item, index) => {
  item = Object.assign({}, item, image[index]);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: I would like to know how you get the image[index] part? Do I create a new array with the image.

Comment: Tried your code it did not work:

let im = filesToEpisode[1].hasOwnProperty("image");
    console.log("CHECKED "+ im);

    if(im){
      const image =[{"image":filesToEpisode[1].image.enclosureurl}];
    //  const array3 = insertEpisode.concat([{"image":"this "}]);
    const array3 = insertEpisode.map((item, index) => {
      item = Object.assign({}, item, image[index]);
    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(array3));
    }

Answer (score -1):

If you need to add an existing image url to your object, can you just assign a new property to the object of your `insertEpisode` array?

```
if (image) {
  insertEpisode[0].image = 'this';
}
```